# Looking for a perfect square

Tags: algorithms, computational-mathematics

I have a base number and I add to this number in increments. Is it possible to calculate where is the nearest perfect square without going through all the numbers?

Example:
Base number 11
Increment value 2 + x

11 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 = 36 (36 being a perfect square)

Comment: Worded a different way, you ask, given a base number $b$, and an initial stepsize, $s$, find the smallest value $f(n)$ with $n$ a non-negative integer such that $f(n)$ is a perfect square, where $f(n):= b + T(n+s)-T(s-1)$ where $T(k)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^k i$ is the $k^{th}$ triangle number...